# Ignore the first option when sorting every select on a page

Tags: javascript, sorting, select

I am trying to sort every select on a page without sorting the first option. I have tried changing a few values but I end up sorting only one of them. This is working now but not ignoring first option for each select:

HTML:

```
<select name="numero_uno" id="numero_uno">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option>Mops</option>
                    <option>Brooms</option>
                    <option>X-wings</option>
                </select>

<select name="number_two" id="number_two">
                <option>Select</option>
                    <option>Cabbage</option>
                    <option>Alfalfa</option>
                    <option>Beets</option>
                </select>
```

Javascript:

```
function sortSelect(e){
    var oA,i,o;oA=[];
    for(i=0;i<e.options.length;i++){
        o=e.options[i];
        oA[i]=new Option(o.text,o.value,o.defaultSelected,o.selected);
    }
    oA.sort(function(a,b){
        var la=a.text.toLowerCase(),lb=b.text.toLowerCase();
        if(la>lb){
            return 1;
        }
        if(la<lb ){
            return-1;
        }
        return 0;
     });
     e.options.length=0;
     for(i=0;i<oA.length;i++){
        e.options[i]=oA[i];oA[i]=null;
     }
     return true;
 }
var eA=document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for(var i=0;i<eA.length;i++){
    sortSelect(eA[i]);
}
```

I have seen some solutions that use jQuery but I want to do this with just javascript.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfX8E/

Comment: Simple workaround, at the beginning of the sort function, assign the first option to a variable, remove it, sort everything, re-insert the first option at the front.

Comment: You should really use more descriptive variable names, my head is hurting from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just change the loops to start from the second option?

```
function sortSelect(e){
    var oA,i,o;oA=[];
    for(i=1;i<e.options.length;i++){
        o=e.options[i];
        oA[i-1]=new Option(o.text,o.value,o.defaultSelected,o.selected);
    }
    oA.sort(function(a,b){
        var la=a.text.toLowerCase(),lb=b.text.toLowerCase();
        if(la>lb){
            return 1;
        }
        if(la<lb ){
            return-1;
        }
        return 0;
     });
     e.options.length=1;
     for(i=0;i<oA.length;i++){
        e.options[i+1]=oA[i];oA[i]=null;
     }
     return true;
 }
var eA=document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for(var i=0;i<eA.length;i++){
    sortSelect(eA[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution I was looking for, but I did not know which values to change to get it working.

Answer (score -1):

Don't add the first option. Sort the select list first and then add the first option at the top.